# Instantiate Spring Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am trying to call two different beans based on my requirement.This two beans are implementing same interface.I have to use two diffrent db's based on data center.How I can do that in springboot application by passing a parameter from application.properties

```
interface Data
{
   string getData(String query)
}



   @Component("oracle")
   class Oracle implements Data
   {
       //getMethod Code Here.
   }


   @Component("sqlserver")
   class SqlServer implements Data
   {
       //getMethod Code Here.
   }
```

Currently I am using

```
  String db = appContext.getBean(propertiesfile.db//getting the value from properties file, Data::class.java)
```

and calling particular db based on return value.But is there anyway I can only instantiate one bean based on app.properties means not using `appContext.getBean`in every request

Comment: Spring Boot already provides this capability for you with the `spring.datasource` properties. You just put `DataSource dataSource` in your service's constructor (or better yet, an R2DBC connection).

Comment: See [The Spring `@ConditionalOnProperty` Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditionalonproperty)

Comment: sorry to misled with question it's just an example i created using two data beans my real life scenario i have to instantiate only one implementation

Comment: Two options - 1) use @ConditionalOnProperty and have separate property files for each deployment. 2) Use Spring's Profile and map with Maven/Gradle's build profile to generate separate jars so that the jar file would contain `spring.profiles.active` on property file to match with build profile. Then use @Profile to optionally initialize the Beans

Comment: I tried to use @@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "db", name = ["service"]),but i still get Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'Data' type when I am autowiring

Comment: If you ask a question supply a real question and not a faulty ”example” also keep updating the question with what code you have tried. Voted to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per suggestions I ended up Using `@ConditionalOnProperty`

This link helped me lot resolving this issue.

https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot-modules/spring-boot-autoconfiguration/src/main/java/com/baeldung/conditionalonproperty